# MPS: Defining baseLanguage predicate in DSL

Tags: mps

I want to have as part of my DSL's `concept` filed which will contain java predicate with following signature `(string -> boolean)`. Which type should I import from baseLanguage to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to import the closures language. FunctionType and ClosureLiteral are the concepts that you are most likely looking for.